# How do I determine this integral? $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin^2(1/x)\frac{dx}{(4+x^2)^2}$

Tags: calculus

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm dx{\sin^2\left({a\over x}\right)\over (4a^2+x^2)^2}$$

$${\sin^2\left({a\over x}\right)\over (4a^2+x^2)^2}={1-\cos^2\left({a\over x}\right)\over (4a^2+x^2)^2}={1\over 2(4a^2+x^2)^2}-{\cos\left({2a\over x}\right)\over 2(4a^2+x^2)^2}$$

$${1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm dx{1\over (4a^2+x^2)^2}-{1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm dx{\cos\left({2a\over x}\right)\over (4a^2+x^2)^2}$$

$${\pi\over 8(2a)^3}-{1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm dx{\cos\left({2a\over x}\right)\over (4a^2+x^2)^2}$$

> $$\int \mathrm dx{1\over (b^2+x^2)^2}={x\over 2b^2(b^2+x^2)}+{1\over 2b^3}\arctan\left({x\over b}\right)+K$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm dx{\cos\left({2a\over x}\right)\over (4a^2+x^2)^2}$$

Enforcing a substitution of $u=\dfrac{2a}{x}$

$${1\over (2a)^3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm du {u^2\cos(u)\over (1+u^2)^2}$$

Now this integral is more harder than the original due to the extra $u^2$ at the numerator.

This is an even function, so can be expressed as

$${1\over 2(2a)^3}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm du {u^2\cos(u)\over (1+u^2)^2}$$

Decomposition of fraction

$${u^2\over (1+u^2)^2}={Au+B\over 1+u^2}+{Cu+B\over (1+u^2)^2}$$

This look like a nightmare, so how do I determine this integral?

Comment: Are you familiar with residues? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Comment: This integral you obtained $${1\over 2(2a)^3}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm du {u^2\cos(u)\over (1+u^2)^2}$$ is exactly the job for Residue theorem. If you are not yet familiar with it, then it becomes more complicated. Clever use of integration by parts might help, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 4):

What I suggest is to write
$$
I\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2\left(\displaystyle \frac{a}{x}\right)}{\left(4a^2+x^2\right)^2}\text{d}x \text{ and }J\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos^2\left(\displaystyle\frac{a}{x}\right)}{\left(4a^2+x^2\right)^2}\text{d}x
$$
Then you have
$$
I\left(a\right)+J\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{d}x}{\left(4a^2+x^2\right)^2}
$$
which can be calculated by using integration by part on
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{d}x}{\left(4a^2+x^2\right)}
$$
which gives you
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{d}x}{\left(4a^2+x^2\right)^2}=\frac{\pi}{32a^3}
$$
Then you can calculate 
$$I(a)-J(a)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos\left(\displaystyle \frac{2a}{x}\right)}{\left(4a^2+x^2\right)^2}\text{d}x=0$$
Hence you have 
$\displaystyle 2I\left(a\right)=\frac{\pi}{32a^3}$ so you can conclude that

> $$
> I\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2\left(\displaystyle \frac{a}{x}\right)}{\left(4a^2+x^2\right)^2}\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{64a^3}$$

Comment: "Then you can calculate $I(a)-J(a)$" - How?

Comment: Using trigonometric formula with $sin^2-cos^2$

Comment: @ Atmos, thank you for adding further details

Comment: Very nice solution by elementary methods!

Answer (score 0):

The value of $a$ is irrelevant, the $a$-parameter can be removed through a suitable substitution, and by replacing $x$ with $\frac{1}{x}$ the problems boils down to computing
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{(4x+1/x)^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{16}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{(x+1/x)^2}\,dx =\frac{1}{16}\left[\frac{\pi}{4}-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{(x+1/x)^2}\,dx\right]$$
or 
$$ \text{Re}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2 e^{ix}}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx\stackrel{\text{Residues}}{=}\color{red}{0} $$
which leads to $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{(4x+1/x)^2}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{64}}$.